# Can Title element have aria-hidden attribute to hide the page title

Tags: html, wai-aria

Can Title element have aria-hidden attribute to hide the page title to be announced when we transition to a different page .
I tried :
1.
‘ <‘title aria-hidden=“true” ‘>’

2. ‘<‘title > < span aria- hidden=“true”> My Title </ title>’

Should that work?- but not working

Also how can I apply the aria attribute to title tag dynamically ?
Not sure how to add aria- hidden to replace
‘<‘title> ‘with  ‘<‘title aria-hidden=“true”> ‘

Thanks

Comment: Hey - not sure what you're showing in your two exemples - is this html ?

Comment: Yes that is HTML , and the editor is not allowing the less than or greater than tag that we add in HTML .my main question is can Title element can have aria- hidden attribute or Title element don’t accept any attributes? Thanks

Comment: Hi Manju, the question editor should allow `<` or `>` by using single or triple backticks.

Answer (score 0):

The Title tag is supposed to go in the head section of your html page, it is therefore not presentational.
The aria-hidden hides presentational element from robot screen readers.
So no, aria-hidden is not for the title tag.